# How can I reference to button trought "tags" in UI Automation?

Tags: xcode, user-interface, automated-tests

UI Automation, xcode
Tested app can be in other languages with buttons with the same functionality.. I would like to know, can I reference to buttton only trought the name .button[NAME] or only by the position data x y? OR there is the way to reference by TAG of BUTTTON, which is in soure code?